# iOS - AdMob making my app crash

Tags: ios, crash, admob

I am trying to add ads to my **iOS app**. Its going well when I testing. But I found 10% crash rate on the Statistical Platform , this is the crash log:

```
libGPUSupportMercury.dylib  _gpus_ReturnNotPermittedKillClient + 12

AGXGLDriver gldUpdateDispatch + 7136

libGPUSupportMercury.dylib  gpusSubmitDataBuffers + 176

AGXGLDriver gldUpdateDispatch + 12704 

WebCore  WebCore::GraphicsContext3D::reshape(int, int) + 528

WebCore WebCore::WebGLRenderingContextBase::initializeNewContext() + 716

WebCore::WebGLRenderingContextBase::WebGLRenderingContextBase(WebCore::HTMLCanvasElement*, WTF::RefPtr<WebCore::GraphicsContext3D>&&, WebCore::GraphicsContext3D::Attributes) + 516

WebCore::WebGLRenderingContext::WebGLRenderingContext(WebCore::HTMLCanvasElement*, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::GraphicsContext3D>, WebCore::GraphicsContext3D::Attributes) + 40

WebCore::WebGLRenderingContextBase::create(WebCore::HTMLCanvasElement*, WebCore::WebGLContextAttributes*, WTF::String const&) + 1276

WebCore::HTMLCanvasElement::getContext(WTF::String const&, WebCore::CanvasContextAttributes*) + 524

11 JavaScriptCore   _llint_entry + 27344
12 JavaScriptCore   _llint_entry + 24760
```